# getting inputs one after the other in from one JTextField java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I'm working on what is supposed to be a basic representation of a bookstore, where a user can add books, textbooks or workbooks to the bookstore(an arraylist). I have to use a GUI for this, and the only elements allowed are a JTextArea, and a JTextField. My problem is that in the actionlistener, the initial input in the textfield just becomes the input for the rest of the prompts that follow it, without allowing the user to put anything in. Is there a way to fix this? Below is a snippet of my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    BookStore b = new BookStore();
    b.setVisible(true);

}
String input;
public BookStore() {

    super("Bookstore");
    setSize(800, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    textField = new JTextField(25);
    panel = new JPanel();
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            /*
                The majority of your code should be written here.
                Note that this scope has access to the fields textField
                and textArea.
            */
            //input = textField.getText();

            if(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) == 1) {
                bookSubMenu();
                textField.setText(null);
                input = textField.getText(); //this just uses the input already present in the JTextField; how can i fix that
                if(Integer.parseInt(input) == 1) {
                    textArea.append("Enter the title of the book: ");
                    tempTitle = textField.getText();//This also uses the input from the original getText() without allowing any input to be entered
                    textArea.append(tempTitle);
                    ret = addBook(BT_BOOK, tempTitle);
                }
                //getBookInfo();
                //textField.setText("");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **actionPerformed** event for a JTextField fires whenever the **Enter** key on your keyboard is hit. This makes it ideal for accepting complete input from the User before processing what he/she has typed. With this in mind, it's a real bad idea to convert input text to integer within this event

```
if(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) == 1) { ... }
```

**unless** you know for certain that the User has actually entered a integer numerical value since an alpha string will definitely produce a **Number Format Exception**. Before you do something like this you need to ensure that the entry is valid for the conversion, perhaps something like this:

```
input = textField.getText();

// If nothing was entered.
if (input.trim().equals("") || input.isEmpty()) {
    textField.setText(null); // In case only whitespaces were entered.
    // Get out of the event. No sense wasting time here.
    return;
}

// Use the String.matches() method with a Regular Expression.
// The "\\d+" checks to see if everything within the textfield
// is a string representation of a integer numerical value.
if (input.matches("\\d+")) { 

    // CODE RELATED TO NUMERICS GOES HERE
}
else {
    // CODE RELATED TO NON-NUMERICS GOES HERE
}
```

Using a boolean variable as a flag or a integer Menu Type selection variable can be set up (better) so that you would always know what the TextField entry is specifically for. It could go something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    input = textField.getText();

    // If nothing was entered.
    if (input.trim().equals("") || input.isEmpty()) {
        textField.setText(null); // In case only whitespaces were entered.
        // Get out of the event. No sense wasting time here.
        return;
    }

    // Use the String.matches() method with a Regular Expression.
    // The "\\d+" checks to see if everything within the textfield
    // is a string representation of a integer numerical value.
    if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
        // The following Integer variable is declared as class global
        // and initialized to 0 (same place the String variable named 
        // input was declared).
        menuItem = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

        // Note: You can use swicth/case for the following...
        if(menuItem == 1) { 
            // Code goes here if 1 was entered
            textArea.append("Enter the title of the book: ");
        }
        else if(menuItem == 2) { 
            // Code goes here if 2 was entered.
        }
        // etc, etc...
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Menu Entry Provided!", 
                                "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            menuItem = 0;
        }
        textField.setText(null);
    }

    // Non-Numerical String entered.
    else {
        // Process String data here.
        // Note: You can use swicth/case for the following...
        if (menuItem == 1) {
            tempTitle = textField.getText();
            textArea.append(tempTitle + System.lineSeparator());
            ret = addBook(BT_BOOK, tempTitle);
        }
        else if (menuItem == 2) {
            // If menuItem 2 is currently active.
        }
        // etc, etc...
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry Provided!\nUndetermined location for content!", 
                                "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            menuItem = 0;
        }
        textField.setText(null);
    }
}
```

You'll get the idea. It's up to you to finish it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So essentially, an actionPerformed fires only once after the enter key is pressed. Then would it be possible to have a menu, with a submenu, and a sub-submenu under a single actionPerformed?

Comment: Yes...as far as I know the event will fire once for every time you hit the ENTER key. "Then would it be possible to have a menu, with a submenu, and a sub-submenu under a single actionPerformed?", I'm not sure what you mean by that. You want to display a menu system when the ENTER key is hit?

Comment: Yes. For example, if 1 is selected from the main menu, a sub menu appears, asking the user to choose either a textbook or a workbook. If the option for workbook is selected, then prompts appear one after the other asking the user for the details of the book, like title, authors, price, etc. Is that possible with just the textfield and textarea?

Comment: It could if its a Popup menu and upon selection of a menu item it supplies a global variable with a specific value that can be used within the very same event that initiated display of the menu.